# Bad array subscript while splitting a string in bash

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to split a string using IFS looking at examples provided at many places. I want to get last element of the array after split, I am doing following to achieve goal :

```
    path_to_file="/home/user/path/to/fileName.txt";
    IFS='/' read -ra split_path <<< "$path_to_file";
    file_name="${split_path[-1]}";
```

It gives the whole string separated by space in a single element in the array. When I run the last command I get error message saying "-bash: split_path: bad array subscript". What I am doing wrong which is not giving me separated elements in different index of array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash 3.x does not understand -1 to mean the last element of an array. You want

```
echo "${split_path[${#split_path[@]}-1]}"
```

Notice also the quoting.

As others have pointed out, `basename` might be a better run for your money, or `${path_to_file##*/}`

Comment: `${path_to_file##*/}`. `-1` should work in newer bash versions though. (It works for me in 4.3.11)

Comment: @PSkocik Thanks for the corrections.  Yeah, this is Bash 3, which I imagine is what the OP is struggling with.

Comment: Although my Bash version is 4.1.2. Your answer is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

with basename ;

```
path_to_file="/home/user/path/to/fileName.txt";
file_name=$(basename "$path_to_file")
echo $file_name
```

with awk;

```
path_to_file="/home/user/path/to/fileName.txt";
file_name=$(echo $path_to_file | awk -F / '{print $NF}') 
echo $file_name
```

or while loop ;

```
path_to_file="/home/user/path/to/fileName.txt";
while IFS='/' read -ra split_path ; do
file_name="${split_path[-1]}";
echo $file_name
done <<<$path_to_file
```

Comment: Variables which contain file names should always be in double quotes.